# Tree view in odoo 11

Tags: odoo-11

I want to show the fields that i mentioned in the tree string when there are no records in my tree view instead of showing  "Click to add a new Sample record."

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="sample_tree_view">
    <field name="name">Sample</field>
    <field name="model">sample.test</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml"
        <tree string="Sample" default_order="name">
            <field name="code" />
            <field name="name" />
            <field name="status" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record> 

<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_sample">
    <field name="name">Sample</field>
    <field name="res_model">sample.test</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
        <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
            Click here to create a new sample Record.
        </p>
    </field>
</record>
```

Thanks in advance ..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove help from your defined action & check.